# Programmatically create Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-app-service-plans

We are trying to automate subscription creation using Azure Automation. The new-AzureRMSubscription needs a module that is in preview mode only.

How do we install the module in Azure Automation Account?

either of the azure and hybrid worker module will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid worker is just a vm, you can install anything you want on it, so you can install those modules. For regular workers, there is a capability to upload modules, so you can just upload a module if its not available directly from the gallery.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-integration-modules

take a look at this as well: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/09/27/upload-powershell-gallery-module-to-azure.aspx or this: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/05/23/creating-your-own-powershell-modules-for-azure-automation-part-1/